# Can i change the default satellite assmbly folder structure?

Tags: .net, wpf, assemblies, cultureinfo

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618(v=vs.80).aspx
It seems like i need to have culture folder under the main executing assembly folder
for example it will be "myprogram/de/", "myprogram/en/"
however, i'm wondering if i could do something like 
"myprogram/resources/de/", "myprogram/resources/en/"
so that i wont have a bunch of resource folders in the main project location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. However, you have to have a .config file.

For example we have a file.exe and in a File.exe.config we have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="Resources;"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Now you have to make sure that this file.exe.config is installed and in the same directory as the .exe file.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i need
we already using <probing> but i try it by adding <probing> elements instead of adding path to the privatePath property
That's why it didn't work, stupid me